# Java, internal windows

Tags: java, swing, jframe, desktop, internal

I have two classes.

One is a calculator (using swing) and another is a desktop-like interface, with a basic menu bar with a button that is supposed to call the calculator.

How can I call the calculator inside of the desktop?

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Answer (score 0):

```
menuItem.addActionListener(new ActionListener {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        if (calculatorFrame.isVisible() == false) { // calculator is not visible and button clicked
              calculatorFrame.setVisible(true);
       } else {
              calculatorFrame.setVisible(false);
       }
   }
```

Essentially, you make your menu item call up the calculatorFrame. Do note, that the calculatorFrame variable must be declared final.

Comment: This doesn't make it an internal frame, this just makes it visible.
http://www.herongyang.com/Swing/JInternalFrame-Internal-Frame-Class-Test.html

I need one of the internal frames to be a pre-existing class.

Comment: Sorry... do take a look at [this](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/JInternalFrame.html)

Comment: So after reading this, I'd have to rewrite all of the objects and variables inside the same class inside of a internal frame?

That seems like I have to rewrite everything I have, and isn't very dynamic if I wanted another pre-written java program inside of my desktop class...